# My Ubuntu 15.10 freeze on my HP 15 Notebook

Tags: drivers, graphics, hp

Recently I installed full Ubuntu 15.10 in my HP 15 Notebook with Windows 8.1 (before), all was fine, but it began to fail, when I'm watching a video in youtube or only use the note writer, the screen freezes and I can't do anything.

I have to shut down from the switch, after the laptop turned on, the screen remains dark and can't do anything, I must return shut down the pc and switch on to make it work again.

My processor is Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU  N3540  @ 2.16GHz,my baseboard is a Hewlett-Packard,Product Name: 2213,Version: 57.51, and the video card is Intel, in the terminal says Intel Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display.

Thank for your time community.